# Script for directory mirroring with inotifywait and ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, inotifywait

I have a script that try to mirror a specific directory from a local server to a remote one. It looks like that:

```
inotifywait -mr --format '%w%f' -e close_write -e moved_to -e delete /mydir | \
while read FILECHANGE
do
    if [ -f $FILECHANGE ]
    then
        rsync --bwlimit=4096 --progress --relative -vrae 'ssh -p 22' $FILECHANGE $REMOTEHOST:/
    else
        ssh -p 22 $REMOTEHOST "rm $FILECHANGE"
    fi
done
```

In case of multiple create of files, as for example a touch command:

`touch 1 2 3`

The 3 files are well transfered.

But if I delete several files at once:

`rm -f 1 2 3`

Only the first 1 is deleted.

If I replace the ssh command by just an `echo $FILECHANGE`, the 3 files are well displayed in the console. So it seems the problem come from the ssh command, but I can't explain why and solve it.

Anyone as an idea?

Comment: It does not answer your question but do you know that rsync can also delete files at destination if they do not exist at source?

Comment: Yes, with the --delete option, if you apply rsync on a directory, I know. But here, I want to apply rsync on a single file. In such a case, if the file does not exist on the origin, rsync exit on an error without doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the issue: it seems that the ssh command was eating the output of the inotifywait command when run. So, to prevent that, I add the 0<&- redirection after the ssh, to close the stdin.

```
inotifywait -mr --format '%w%f' -e close_write -e moved_to -e delete /mydir | \
while read FILECHANGE
do
    if [ -f $FILECHANGE ]
    then
        rsync --bwlimit=4096 --progress --relative -vrae 'ssh -p 22' $FILECHANGE $REMOTEHOST:/
    else
        ssh -p 22 $REMOTEHOST "rm $FILECHANGE" 0<&-
    fi
done
```

Now it works.